# Como eu faço para pesquisar algo em html css js?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Então Pessoal, eu queria poder pesquisar items em html, sem um banco, pois os itens não serão acrescentados de forma dinâmica, já serão pré-estabelecidos, como sou iniciante não faço ideia de como fazer isso, se alguém puder me ajudar eu agradeço desde já.

```css
ul{
list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Pesquise aqui">
<ul>
<li>Abacate</li>
<li>Banana</li>
<li>Cenoura</li>
<li>Tomate</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Aí está.
A lógica é simples: a cada vez que uma tecla é pressionada dentro do `input`, o código Javascript gera uma *expressão regular* com o valor do `input`, expressão essa que é comparada ao texto de cada item da lista. Os items cujo texto não corresponde à ela recebem `display: none;` em seu css, para que fiquem ocultos. Já os que correspondem, ficam com `display: block;`

**Obs:** o script só funciona para encontrar items que **COMEÇAM** com o que foi digitado. "Maçã verde", por exemplo, não seria encontrada apenas digitando a palavra "verde".

```js
const campoPesquisa = document.querySelector('#pesquisa');
const items = document.querySelectorAll('#lista li');
let regexCheck;

campoPesquisa.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  regexCheck = new RegExp(`^${e.target.value}`, 'i');  
  items.forEach(item => {
    if (!item.innerText.match(regexCheck)) {
      item.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      item.style.display = 'block';
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#lista {
  list-style: none;
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="pesquisa" placeholder="Pesquise aqui">
<ul id="lista">
  <li>Abacate</li>
  <li>Banana</li>
  <li>Cenoura</li>
  <li>Tomate</li>
</ul>
```